# Why does moving one side of my rigged character move the other side as well?

Tags: animation, armature

Hi I'm new to Blender and I was trying to animate a character. I set the mesh parent to the armature with automatic weights, and when I tried to move the left arm the right arm moves in the same way (same situation with every symmetric body parts). The armature on the other side doesn't move, just the character. Could someone please help me with making each body part move independently?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You probably have a mirror modifier below(i.e. after) the armature modifier. Move the mirror modifier above the armature, or better, apply the mirror modifier at this point so  you can rig and animate the character.

Answer (score 1):

## Why?

As Mike Pan mentioned- this is because you have a mirror modifier on your mesh, **not** your armature.

## How to fix

Either A. Apply the modifier or B. Remove it

-Happy Blendering!